# Comparing dates using struts 2 in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, ognl

I want to compare two dates using `Struts2`

```
One is returned from the backend  (test.currentDate) == "2012-11-15)"
The other one I just set "2014-10-19"
```

How can I compare the two dates?

My code is as follows:

```
<s:set name="currentDate"  value="%{test.currentDate}"/>
<s:set name="futureDate" value="2014-10-19"/>
<s:if test="%{#currentDate.before(#futureDate)}">
    <s:text name="test"/> <s:date name="test.currentDate" format="MM/yy"/> 
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <s:text name="test2"/>
</s:else>
```

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket after `.before(#futureDate`

Comment: My advice: Put this kind of logic in the action and be happy. Struts2 logic tags with OGNL, except for the most trivial tests/control structures, are a PITA, and are difficult to debug and mantain.

Comment: i don't have control on the action class...

Comment: What's the actual question? Are you saying it doesn't work? If so, describe *how* it doesn't work. Did you sanity-check the data you're working with? Are they dates, or strings? Any exceptions?

Comment: <s:date name="test.currentDate" format="MM/yy"/>   this is working.. i can see the date in the screen

Comment: no exception.. everything goes to the else statement

Comment: which type is `currentDate`? `Date` or `String`

Comment: You could pass the logic to the action if you can't use expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the above you were trying compare string with date object that's causing the problem.
I suggest you to write a helper class to compare date and take the advantage of OGNL static method access. [OGNLBasics-Accessingstaticproperties](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl-basics.html#OGNLBasics-Accessingstaticproperties)

```
    <s:set var="currentDate" value="%{new java.util.Date()}"/>
    <s:set var="futureDate" value="%{new java.util.Date()}"/>
    <s:property value="{#currentDate}"/>
    <s:property value="{#futureDate}"/>
    <s:if test="%{@com.mycompany.temp.strtus2.example.HelloWorld@compareDate(#currentDate, #futureDate)}">
        <div>Do your stuff</div>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        <div>else condition</div>
    </s:else>
```

Util Class

```
public static boolean compareDate(Date currentDate, Date futureDate) {
    boolean flag = false;
    if (removeTime(currentDate).equals(removeTime(futureDate))) {
        flag = true;
    } 
    return flag;
}

public static Date removeTime(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get a timestamp long value for your `futureDate`, (e.g. 2014-10-19 == 1413706569870) then in JSP

```
<s:if test="1413706569870l > test.currentDate.time">
```

or

```
<s:if test="test.currentDate.before(new java.util.Date(1413706569870l))">
```

Comment: how can i test this <s:date name="test.currentDate" format="MM/yy"/> ??

Comment: how do you compute for the timestamp?

Comment: You are expecting the later of the two to return false correct?

Comment: Updated. Was missing "l" after timestamp to indicate that is long value.